# KendoUI Cascading Dropdowns -- Retrieving json data from dropdown to use in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui

Oh boy what did I get myself into this time. Have to get some KendoUI cascading dropdrown lists working properly but I figure I will start off with two for now. Basically I need to retrieve whatever the user chooses for the first list in the view and send that back to the controller then pass it to an Entity Framework method (which I already have setup). Here is what I have now. The controller then passes back the appropriate 2nd dropdown list based on the first dropdown division value selected. I have tried using the Kendo stringify(data) trick in the parametermap as well as using cascadeFrom: "division", as suggested in the kendoui docs but that hasnt worked so far. Thus leading me to this interesting creation so far.

Any help or Garfield Comics are greatly appreciated.

The JS for the dropdownlists;

```
var divisions = $("#division").kendoDropDownList({
    optionLabel: "Select category...",
    dataTextField: "CodeAndDescription",
    dataValueField: "Code",
    dataSource: {
        // type: "odata",
        serverFiltering: true,
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: VIPApiUrl + "GetDivision",
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                type: "POST",
            }, parameterMap: function (options, type) {

                // edit VARS passed to service here!
                if (type === 'read') {
                    return {
                        'division': options.division,
                        // 'criteria[0].Value': options.value
                        // ...
                    };
                }
            }
        }
    },
    change: function () {
        var value = this.value();
        alert(value);
        if (value) {
            itemGroupDataSource.one("change", function () {
                itemGroup.current(null);
            }).filter({
                field: "ID",
                operator: "eq",
                value: parseInt(value)
            });
            itemGroup.enable();
        } else {
            itemGroup.enable(false);
        }

        itemGroup.select(0);
    }
}).data("kendoDropDownList");

var itemGroupDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    //type: "odata",
    serverFiltering: true,
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: VIPApiUrl + "GetItemGroup",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            type: "POST",

        }
    }
});I
```

My controller where I need to access the json:

```
#region GetItemGroup
    [HttpPost]
    public List<ItemGroupsDTO> GetItemGroup(JObject jsonData)
    {
        dynamic json = jsonData;
        string x = null; //intentionally pass null values
        string division = json.division;


        List<ItemGroupsDTO> ItemGroups = new List<ItemGroupsDTO>();

        var ItemGroupEOList = new VIPItemGroupBOList();


        ItemGroupEOList.Load(x, x, division, x, x, x, x, x, x, x, false);

        foreach (var d in ItemGroupEOList)
        {
            var ItemGroup = new ItemGroupsDTO();
            ItemGroup.Code = d.Code;
            ItemGroups.Add(ItemGroup);
        }

        return ItemGroups;
    }
    #endregion
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I fixed this by changing the parameter map in the itemGroupDataSource to:

```
parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
            return {
                division: options.filter.filters[0].value
            }
        }
```

and changed the value field to:

```
dataValueField: "CodeAndDescription",
```

So I am guessing I partly wasn't giving the EO the right information but hopefully this helps someone in a Jam.